# How to Validate following field using presave function?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to validate "Email" and "Approval" Field to have information before user submits it. How can I use presave function to check for the validation?

[Here is my SP form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8UWh.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider to use [list validation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/examples-of-common-formulas-in-sharepoint-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)?

Fake formula:

```
=IF([Field]="condition",IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK([Email]),NOT(ISBLANK([Approval])),TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

If list validation can't meet your  requirement, then, you may consider to use PreSaveAction